# How is Microsoft Store remembering apps from a previous Windows installation?

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-store

I have noticed that on a clean installation of Windows, Microsoft Store remembers apps that were downloaded on a previous install, even though (1) I have never signed into a Microsoft account on Windows, and (2) the system disk has been wiped *completely clean* (using `diskpart clean`).

What unique identifier is Microsoft Store using to maintain this association with the machine? I was not signed into a Microsoft account, and there was no data left on the system drive. Is Microsoft Store using some kind of machine-specific identifier or fingerprint?

And why is it presumed that this is acceptable - what if the machine had been wiped and sold to a new user, for instance?

Comment: your windows 11 digital license tells Microsoft who you are.

Comment: Are any of these applications ones that are from your computer manufacturer?

Comment: Unsubscribe before reinstalling Windows. Also do not use the Store. If you use it, they will know you. Standard marketing everywhere.

Comment: "What unique identifier is Microsoft Store using to maintain this association with the machine?" - Your Microsoft Account.  "Is Microsoft Store using some kind of machine-specific identifier or fingerprint?" - No; It's not since you are not logged into a Microsoft Account.  How did you determine that the Microsoft Store downloaded non-provisioned applications?